# Google Drive API acces oauth client ID in release

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have project and app registered in Google API Console (Cloud Console now).
My app is "native" (Java) and it has a OAuth 2.0 Client ID for Drive API access. 

**Do I need another client ID for my release version?**

I know it should work ok with the testing one, but I think it would affect the traffic quota if I use the same client ID in testing and release... I definitely need advice guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Do I need another client ID for my release version?" No you don't need to, but you could if you wanted to. It mostly depends on your test harness and workflow. Most quotas are generous enough that you shouldn't be hitting them. The most onerous quota is the undocumented burst restriction, but having multiple client Ids is unlikely to benefit you much.